# Using jQuery to dynamically add Prev Next as Bootstrap Modal buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog, dynamically-generated

I seem to be having a problem with adding buttons dynamically using jQuery and having these buttons go missing. I have verified that these button were previously added to the DOM.

I have this [codepen](https://codepen.io/KerryRuddock/pen/dmNZOq) that contains 4 buttons. Each button opens a modal as can be seen in the attached image below

[image]

I am using jQuery to add Prev and Next buttons to each modal, except for the first modal adds only a Next button, the last modal adds only a Prev button. I am using jQuery to perform this task.  Here's the code:

```
$(function() {

  var $modals = $('[data-toggle="modal"]');
  var mCount = $modals.length;
  var el = $('.modal-footer').children();

  var prevButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Prev</button>");
 var nextButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>');


  for (var i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
    if ( i === 0 ) {
      $(el[i]).after(nextButton);
    } else if ( i === mCount -1 ) {
      $(el[i]).before(prevButton);
    } else {
      $(el[i]).before(prevButton);
      $(el[i]).after(nextButton); 
    }
  }
});
```

I have run a trace with Chrome Dev Tools setting a breakpoint at the end of each loop, I see the buttons are created. However, during the next iteration, buttons that were added are disappearing from the DOM. Hoping someone could shed some light as to what I am doing wrong.

The 1st modal footer in my HTML after jQuery had completed 1 loop. Pasted from chrome dev tools this shows that the Next button was added: (good so far)

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
</div>
```

After the 2nd loop. 1st modal footer no longer has a Next button, but 2nd modal footer has added Prev and Next buttons. (How did button on 1st modal get removed?)

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Prev</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
</div>
```

After the 3nd loop. 2nd modal footer no longer has Prev and Next buttons. 3rd modal footer has added Prev and Next buttons.

After the 4th loop, 3rd modal footer's Prev button is removed (why?), the 4th modal footer is correct. No missing buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var prevButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Prev</button>");
```

to

```
var prevButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Prev</button>";
```

(ie remove the `$()` wrapper)

When you use `$("..")` you create a new node and `.after`/`.before` *moves* that node to the new location.

When you use plain text, it create a new node for you each time, so won't move it.

Comment: Great Answer.  Probably saved me future encounters of repeating this bug as I was get my information from the workings slides at http://try.jquery.com/levels/3/sections/4.  Which was telling me to put this in the $() wrapper.

Comment: To be fair, that slide is correct, but only in the very limited scenario that it's used - ie *adding* one `<p>`.  Didn't go too far in those slides as they're so hard to read, but the next one says `price.appendTo($('.vacation'));` which is also confusing as it could just be `price.appendTo('.vacation');`

Comment: You could also have declared the `var prevButton` *inside* the for loop and it would have worked as it would be a different button each time.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your codepen. Please check here.

https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/Ldxrey

```
// javascript object patterns
$(function() {

  var $modals = $('[data-toggle="modal"]');
  var mCount = $modals.length;
  var el = $('.modal-footer').children();

  var prevButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Prev</button>";
 var nextButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>';

  for (var i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
    if ( i === 0 ) {
      $(el[i]).after(nextButton);
    } else if ( i === mCount -1 ) {
      $(el[i]).before(prevButton);
    } else {
      $(el[i]).before(prevButton);
      $(el[i]).after(nextButton); 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers